# Failed to render form input field in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, formtastic

I use [activeadmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) (activeadmin use [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) and devise) for the admin panel, 
But I can not display following two fields(these are in a regular model, nothing to do with  authentication, I just want to display them in the view page).

1. password_value:  binary
2. admin: boolean

Take `password_value` for example, below are the three way I have tried:

```
form do |f|
   f.input :origin
   f.input :password_value
end
```

this code will raise `Formtastic::UnknownInputError` exception in activeadmin-0.4.4/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb

```
form do |f|
   f.input :origin
   f.input :password_value, :as => :string
end
```

in this code, `password_value` will not be displayed on the view page

```
form do |f|
   f.input :origin
   f.inputs do
     f.input :password_value, :as => :string
   end
end
```

in this code, `password_value` will be displayed on the view page, but in a separated group or div( I want it to reside in the same fieldset as `origin` does).

So I want to

- display them correctly
- in the same fieldset as others.

Any help is appreciated, and Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the whole resource file in your app/admin folder?

Comment: Just as simple as `ActiveAdmin.register PasswordForm do ... end` and ... is the code above I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do the following :

Add point 2 (displays in the same fieldset):

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
   f.input :admin
   f.input :password_value, :as => :string
  end
end
```

`f.inputs` is grouping the fields inside the do block in a fieldset.

To show them correctly :

You said `password_value` is shown correctly, even if it is binary? Sorry but I didn't cover showing binaries in formtastic.